# Ignored properties and simple swift properties

Tags: ios, swift, properties, realm

What is the difference in behavior of using ignored properties and just using simple swift property?

I need to add properties to realm object which should not be save to DB. Realm provides "ignored properties" but if I just write properties with ordinary swift style, it should't be saved to DB. Is there difference in behavior?

```
// Ignored propery
class Person: Object {
  dynamic var tmpID = 0

  override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["tmpID"]
  }
}


// Normal swift property
class Person: Object {
      var tmpID = 0 // Realm supported class but with no dynamic
      var myClassObj = MyCustomClass() // Class realm does not support
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to e comparing `ignoredProperties` with these two things

- a swift property without `dynamic`
- a property that is of a type not supported by Realm

For the first kind, Realm seems to still store these in the database.

```
class MyObject: Object {
    dynamic var string = ""
    var normalString = ""
}
```

And the database:

[image]

This is because `dynamic` is just a way to tell swift to use dynamic dispatch in the Objective-C runtime, which allows the properties to be updated dynamically at runtime.

For the second kind, Realm seems to ignore your custom classes that are not Realm `Object`s.

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, I am not seeing this behavior with Swift 4, Realm 3. If a Realm class property is designated as a var, as shown in the answer, Realm does not appear to persist it (store it) in Realm. Also note for Swift 4, the Realm properties need to be defined as @objc dynamic var

Answer (score 2):

There may be other reasons to do it the Realm way and use `ignoredProperties`, but one problem I see would be the following.

Realm is a C++ project, above is a Objective-C layer and on top of that sits the Swift layer. I think it is likely that one day the Objective-C layer will be dropped. 
If you upgrade your database after that day, all your simple swift properties would become database entries, because `dynamic` tells the compiler to use Objective-C dynamic dispatch. If they drop the Objective-C layer, `dynamic` would no longer be needed. So be save and use `ignoredProperties`.

Answer (score 2):

It is mandatory to mark `var` properties in Realm models as `dynamic` due to the Objective-C runtime that is used in the Realm framework. If you don't mark properties as `dynamic`, they won't be updated in runtime.

However, `ignoredProperties` is a completely independent thing. By adding a property to `ignoredProperties`, you tell Realm not to persist that property in the database. If you don't mark a property as `dynamic` and don't add it to `ignoredProperties` either, it will still be persisted to Realm, but it won't work as expected.

If you need to store properties in your Realm model class that are not to be persisted, you have to add them to `ignoredProperties`.